# Creating multiple EBS volumes using AWS EC2_instance module

Tags: amazon-web-services, count, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Count index is not working inside ebs_block_device,
any advice on how to make it work?
This is an example of code that I am using.
As an output, it creates only first drive in the count.

```
module "ec2_instance" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  count = "${var.count_ec2}"
  name = "${var.name}${count.index + 1 }"

  ami                    = var.ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  key_name               = var.key_name
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_id]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id

  root_block_device = [
    {
      volume_type = var.root_drive_type
      volume_size = var.root_drive_size
      encrypted   = true
      kms_key_id  = var.kms_key
    }
]

  ebs_block_device = [
    {
      count       = "${var.count_drives}"
      device_name = "${element(var.ebs_devices_names, count.index)}"
      volume_type = var.ebs_drives_type
      volume_size = "${element(var.ebs_devices_size, count.index)}"
      encrypted   = true
      delete_on_termination = false
      kms_key_id  = var.kms_key

    },
]
```

Comment: "not working inside ebs_block_device" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: terraform plan gives information that only one block device will be created, instead of 4 as it set in var.count_drives

Comment: Commented ebs_block_device, and used aws_ebs_volume/aws_volume_attachment, and it works. Creates 4 EBS volumes as it should. Does it mean that count is not working in ebs_block_device in terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws module? Or was there my mistake in the code?

Answer (score 2):

`count` is an invalid parameter of `ebs_block_device`. If you want to create multiple ebs volumes, you have to list them all using **for loop** for exmaple:

```
ebs_block_device = [for index in var.count_drives:
    {
      device_name = "${element(var.ebs_devices_names, index)}"
      volume_type = var.ebs_drives_type
      volume_size = "${element(var.ebs_devices_size, index)}"
      encrypted   = true
      delete_on_termination = false
      kms_key_id  = var.kms_key

    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, will check it on Monday. It should work!

Comment: @Alex No problem. Let me know how it will go. If you will find it useful, then the acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a suggestion to have a loop for the ebs_block_device where the loop will stop if the added ebs_block_device is equal to or more than the value configured for var.volume_count.

```
dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
for_each = {
for k,v in var.id : k => v
if k < var.volume_count
}
content {
device_name = "/dev/sd${ebs_block_device.value}"
volume_type = var.volume_type
volume_size = var.volume_size
delete_on_termination = var.delete_on_termination
}
```

where in the variables.tf you can have something like below :

```
variable "id" {
  type        = list
  description = "part of ID to identify each volume"
  default     = ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l" ,"m", "n", "o", "p", 
                 "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
}
```